# Visual Studio 2017: Package Restore failed, Rolling back Package changes for 'Projectname'

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package-restore

Added the new Package using Package Manager console or manage nuget packages in Project it's not added project it's Throw below Error.

I was Check some Links Not give proper reason. why this problem in coming in vs2017

Anyone Know Share the knowledge.

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You should share the detail error info in the output window.

Comment: @Leo-MSFT  i was try to add the exceldatareader.dataset  package using manage nuget packages  i get this error. i was searched the given solution not worked for me

Comment: @Leo-MSFT it's a uwp application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Visual Studio 2017: Package Restore failed, Rolling back Package changes for 'Projectname'

You could not install the package `exceldatareader.dataset` to the UWP project. That because **this package only have the .NET Framework assemblies, which is not compatible with UWP project**. You can download that package from [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader.DataSet/), then open it, you will find this package only have the assemblies for .NET 2.0 and .NET 4.5:

[image]

So this package is not compatible with UWP project, you can find the error message in the output window when you install it to the UWP project:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks  @Leo-MSFT. Any other excel reader package you know for excel reading. the EPP.Core I also used the Not Getting data from sheet. any package are you know please share me.

Comment: @umasankar, you can try to use ExcelDataReader package, which lightweight and fast library written in C# for reading Microsoft Excel files, it can be installed for UWP project. Hope helps.